# ¿Por qué no me calcula la longitud del array?

Tags: c

Este programa debería poder diferenciar si la primera letra de mi palabra es minúscula o mayúscula, pero solo lo hace si la primera letra es una 'a' o 'A' y no debería hacer eso.

Me seria de mucha ayuda si alguien pudiera encontrar cual es el problema, ya que probé también comparar directamente los caracteres como char haciendo en lugar de un array de `int` con los valores ASCII un array de `char` con los caracteres directamente y sigue sin funcionar.

```
int ascii(char letra)
{
    int valorAscii = letra;
    return valorAscii;
}

int eso(char letra,int alfabeto[])
{
    int longitud=sizeof(alfabeto)/sizeof(*alfabeto);
    for(int i = 0; i < longitud; i++)
    {
        if(ascii(letra) == alfabeto[i])
        {
            return 1;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}

int main()
{
    int may[] = {65,66,67,68,69,70,71,72,73,74,75,76,77,78,79,80,81,82,83,84,85,86,87,88,89,90};
    int min[] = {97,98,99,100,101,102,103,104,105,106,107,108,109,110,111,112,113,114,115,116,117,118,119,120,121,122};
    char palabra[20];
    printf("INGRESE UNA PALABRA \n");
    scanf("%s",&palabra);
    fflush(stdin);
    printf("%d \n",eso(palabra[0],may));
    printf("%d \n",eso(palabra[0],min));
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: El título original estaba *chulo* ... pero nadie con tu mismo problema podría encontrar esta publicación. Lo he cambiado por una mas *realista*, espero que no te moleste.

Comment: gracias por tu comentario @Trauma pero no veo en que me ayuda la pregunta que me enviaste para que mire y creo que no estas entendiendo mi problema, no tengo un problema con punteros, mi problema es que si probas alguna letra en ese progrma que no sea la 'a' el progrma devuelve el mismo valor para mayuscula o minuscula. gracias igual por tu comentario. vuelvo a poner el titulo que estaba porqeu creo que no comprendiste mi problmea  y puede traer confusiones

Comment: Jejeje ... me temo que el que no entiende nada del problema **eres tú**. Intenta entender la pregunta a la que te remito. O espera una respuesta ... y veras :-)

Comment: @Trauma como dije antes no comprendiste mi problema, ya logre solucionarlo creando 2 funciones nuevas y pasando como paramentro la primera letra de mi palabra original. igual gracias por tu comentario me ayudo a seguir investigando.

Comment: Cuando puedas, intenta averiguar el resultado de esto: `int longitud=sizeof(alfabeto)/sizeof(*alfabeto)` **en el sitio en donde lo usas**. Y podemos seguir hablando de cual era tu problema :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El parámetro `alfabeto` en realidad no es un *array*, sino, un puntero.

```c
int eso(char letra, int alfabeto[]) { ... }
```

Es decir, el compilador convierte el segundo parámetro a un puntero:

```c
int eso(char letra, int* alfabeto) { ... }
```

Sabiendo esto, el resultado que devuelve `sizeof(alfabeto)` en una máquina de 32 bits sería `4` bytes (que básicamente es el tamaño en bytes que consume el puntero) y el `sizeof(*alfabeto)` devolvería la cantidad de bytes que ocupe la variable al que apunte el puntero `alfabeto`, que en este caso, sería `4` bytes.

Sabiendo todo esto, el valor que recibe la variable `longitud` sería `1`:

```c
int longitud = sizeof(alfabeto) / sizeof(*alfabeto);
int longitud =            4     /        4
int longitud =                 1
```

Ese es el problema, esa expresión no calcula la longitud del array. Evidentemente, este resultado solo sucedería en una máquina de 32 bits.

El resultado en una máquina de 64 bits sería:

```c
int longitud = sizeof(alfabeto) / sizeof(*alfabeto);
int longitud =            8     /        4
int longitud =                 2
```

Entendiendo lo anterior, podríamos responder a esta duda:

> > Este programa deberia poder diferenciar si la primera letra de mi palabra es minuscula o mayuscula, pero solo lo hace si la primera letra es una 'a' o 'A'

Claro, solo funcionará para las letras `'a'` y `'A'` porque la longitud que calculaste fue `1` y no permitirá recorrer todo el *array*.

La solución a este problema, es pasar la longitud del *array* a un parámetro de la función:

```c
#include <stdio.h>

int ascii(char letra)
{
    int valorAscii = letra;
    return valorAscii;
}

int eso(char letra, int alfabeto[], int longitud)
{
    for(int i = 0; i < longitud; i++)
    {
        if(ascii(letra) == alfabeto[i])
        {
            return 1;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}

int main()
{
    int may[] = {65,66,67,68,69,70,71,72,73,74,75,76,77,78,79,80,81,82,83,84,85,86,87,88,89,90};
    int min[] = {97,98,99,100,101,102,103,104,105,106,107,108,109,110,111,112,113,114,115,116,117,118,119,120,121,122};
    char palabra[20];
    printf("INGRESE UNA PALABRA \n");
    scanf("%s",&palabra);
    fflush(stdin);
    printf("%d \n", eso(palabra[0], may, sizeof may / sizeof *may));
    printf("%d \n", eso(palabra[0], min, sizeof min / sizeof *min));
    return 0;
}
```

Por supuesto, puedes ocultar esa expresión (el que calcula la longitud del array) en una macro:

```c
#define ESO(letra, array) eso(letra, may, sizeof array / sizeof *array))
```

Y luego lo puedes usar de esta forma:

```c
#include <stdio.h>

#define ESO(letra, array) eso(letra, may, sizeof array / sizeof *array)

int ascii(char letra)
{
    int valorAscii = letra;
    return valorAscii;
}

int eso(char letra, int alfabeto[], int longitud)
{
    for(int i = 0; i < longitud; i++)
    {
        if(ascii(letra) == alfabeto[i])
        {
            return 1;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}

int main()
{
    int may[] = {65,66,67,68,69,70,71,72,73,74,75,76,77,78,79,80,81,82,83,84,85,86,87,88,89,90};
    int min[] = {97,98,99,100,101,102,103,104,105,106,107,108,109,110,111,112,113,114,115,116,117,118,119,120,121,122};
    char palabra[20];
    printf("INGRESE UNA PALABRA \n");
    scanf("%19s", palabra);
    printf("%d \n", ESO(palabra[0], may));
    printf("%d \n", ESO(palabra[0], min));
    return 0;
}
```

Y de esta forma ya no necesitas pasar explicitamente la longitud del array, sino, la macro lo hace por ti.

De igual manera, esta solución no es tan eficiente, ya que necesita tener el alfabeto en memoria y de paso, debe realizar una búsqueda lineal.

Una solución más simple sería:

```c
#include <stdio.h>

#define esMay(letra) (letra >= 'A' && letra <= 'Z')
#define esMin(letra) (letra >= 'a' && letra <= 'z')

int main()
{
    char palabra[20];
    printf("INGRESE UNA PALABRA \n");
    scanf("%19s", palabra);
    printf("%d \n", esMay(palabra[0]));
    printf("%d \n", esMin(palabra[0]));
    return 0;
}
```

### Observaciones:

**1.-** En este caso no necesitas limpiar el búfer del teclado y si fuera necesario, no uses la función [fflush](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/fflush/), ya que esta rutina es expresamente para vaciar el búfer **stdout** y no para el **stdin**.

Una forma estándar de limpiar el búfer **stdin** sería:

```c
int ch;
while((ch = getchar()) != '\n' && ch != EOF);
```

**2.-** Sí vas a usar la función *scanf* para leer cadenas, acostumbra especificar el tamaño del array en el primer parámetro, así evitas un posible desbordamiento de búfer.

```c
//No se coloca 20, porque se debe dejar un espacio para el caracter nulo.
scanf("%19s", palabra);
```

**3.-** No hace falta anteponer el *ampersand* en este caso:

```c
scanf("%s", &palabra);
```

Ya que el identificador `palabra` es un alias de la dirección base del array. Por ende, en ambos casos darán el mismo resultado:

```c
printf("%p = %p\n", &palabra, palabra);
```

Comment: gracias maestro

Answer (score 1):

usando estas 2 funciones y pasando como parametro la primera letra de la palabra que use pude solucionar mi problema.

```
int esMayuscula(char letra)
{
    if(letra>= 'A' && letra <= 'Z')
    {
        return 1;
    }
    return 0;
}
int esMinuscula(char letra)
{
    if(letra>= 'a' && letra <= 'z')
    {
        return 1;
    }
    return 0;
}
```